# Is there a strong version of twin prime conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The twin prime conjecture states that :

> There exists infinitely many integers such that $n$ and $n+2$ are both primes

for a fixed $k$, can we find integers $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k$ such that:

> There exists infinitely many integers such that $n,n+a_1,\cdots,n+a_k$ are primes.

My try: for example we can state $a_1=2$ for $k=2$, I proved also that $n,n+2$ and $n+4$ can not be all primes, the same thing for $n$ and $n+2$ and $n+t$ with t an odd integer, but nothing for $t=8$

Comment: This is a notorious open question, called the prime $k$-tuple conjecture, also known as Hardy-Littlewood First Conjecture.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for thanks!